# C# How to represent (unsigned long)(unsigned int) (ulong)(uint) with XOR (^)

Tags: c#, xor, uint, ulong

I'm converting C++ code to C#

Say I got this in C++

```
int v5;
v5 = (*(_DWORD *)(v4 + 68) ^ (unsigned __int64)(unsigned int)(*(_DWORD *)(v4 + 56) ^ *(_DWORD *)(v4 + 20))) % 9;
```

In C# it would be like..

```
   int v5;
   v5 = (int)((BitConverter.ToInt32(v4, 68) ^ (ulong)(uint)(BitConverter.ToInt32(v4, 56) ^ BitConverter.ToInt32(v4, 20))) % 9);
```

But I get errors.. with the `(ulong)` , `(uint)`

> Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'ulong'

Should I do

```
(int)(ulong)(uint)(...)
```

or what?

Comment: The type of `v4` is relevant, please provide it.

Comment: Why not use BitConvert.ToUint64?

Comment: v4 is int.. just a pointer scanner, convert what to UInt64?

Comment: believe me all that `*(_DWORD *)(v4 + XX)` crap is handled by `BitConverter.ToInt32(v4, XX)` extremely well.. I've tested this with other snippets.. but this one really got me stumped. with xor.. and ulong

Comment: Use `BitConvert.ToUInt32` instead of `ToInt32` and lose some of the casts. A faithful conversion should be something like : `(int)((BitConvert.ToUInt32(v4, 68) ^ (ulong)BitConvert.ToUInt32(v4, 56) ^ BitConvert.ToUInt32(v4, 20)) % 9);`

Comment: wow user786653 that works PERFECTLY!! Thank you very much, god bless you, post it as a answer.. and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BitConvert.ToUInt32` (corresponds to the `DWORD` type from Win32 C++ programming) instead of `ToInt32` (normally an `int`), that should help you lose some of the casts and fix some of the type problems.

A faithful conversion should be something like the following, though I don't think it's necessary to have the intermediate cast to `ulong` (Since the 32 most significant bits are ignored when we do the mod 9 anyway and I think they'll always end up as 0):

```
(int)((BitConvert.ToUInt32(v4, 68) ^ (ulong)BitConvert.ToUInt32(v4, 56) ^ BitConvert.ToUInt32(v4, 20)) % 9);
```